# Obj-c extension does not work in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Trying to use a obj-c extension in my swift project:

UIBezierPath+hello.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIBezierPath(hello)

- (void)hello;

@end
```

UIBezierPath+hello.m

```
#import "UIBezierPath+hello.h"


@implementation UIBezierPath(hello)

- (void)hello
{
    NSLog (@"hello hello");
}

@end
```

Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "UIBezierPath+hello.h"
```

Swift

```
let helloPath = UIBezierPath()
helloPath.hello()
```

It does build and it does sees the hello method. But it does crush:

> -[UIBezierPath hello]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d2116d0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',  reason: '-[UIBezierPath hello]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d2116d0'

It seems it does not recognises the implementation.
Probably it does not work because I am dumb:)
Custom obj-c classes work in swift. Only extension give me this problem

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably means that you forgot to tick the "Target" checkbox when adding  "UIBezierPath+hello.m" to the project, so that the file is not compiled and linked
to the executable.

Adding the "Target Membership" in the File inspector should solve the problem.

Comment: Yep, my fault. I did rename the file and Xcode unchecked it from the target! Thanks!